# SQL SELECT rows in a table if the given condition is a substring of the column data with a separator ';' between the substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get rows from the table Mails if the column [To] has the mail abc@mail.

The simple solution would be `Select * from Mails where [To] = 'abc@mail'`

But the thing is [To] column has data like 123@mail;abc@mail;aabc@mail etc separated by semicolons
where To is multiple emails sent

I know I could do something like `Select * from Mails where [To] like '%abc@mail%'` but that won't solve the problem if the given mail is a substring of another mail. I thought of a split string solution

I have a split_string function like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split_string]
(
@string_value NVARCHAR(MAX),
@delimiter_character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @result_set TABLE(splited_data NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE @start_position INT,
        @ending_position INT
SELECT @start_position = 1,
        @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter_character, @string_value)
WHILE @start_position < LEN(@string_value) + 1
        BEGIN
    IF @ending_position = 0 
       SET @ending_position = LEN(@string_value) + 1
    INSERT INTO @result_set (splited_data) 
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string_value, @start_position, @ending_position - @start_position))
    SET @start_position = @ending_position + 1
    SET @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter_character, @string_value, @start_position)
END
RETURN
END
```

which would return splitted string of a single data in a column and the function is working fine.

I tried executing the query

```
Select * 
from Mails 
where 'abc@mail' in (
   Select * 
   from dbo.split_string((SELECT [To] FROM Mails) , ';')
)
```

which is throwing the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

I need help proceeding from here. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Side note, Multi-line table value functions are known to perform *awfully*. `WHILE` loops also perform *very* poorly. I strongly suggest that if you need to use a user defined function you make an **inline** table value function with a set based solution; it will significantly more performant.

Comment: If you do want a string splitter, I suggest looking into CLR functions, an XML splitter, or a tally splitter (like `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`/`DelimitedSplitN4k_LEAD`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**
Here is the query that you want

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Mails AS m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.split_string(m.[To], ';') s
    WHERE s.splited_data = 'abc@mail'
)
```

I recommend the splitting approach. Any character lookup will have to account the variability of the semi-colons, whereas splitting it out will handle the ambiguity of where the semi-colons are, and then you can do a direct equality check. If you wanted to take it a step further and look for additional [To] addresses you can just add an IN clause like this and SQL Server doesn't have to do much more work and you get the same results.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Mails AS m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.split_string(m.[To], ';') s
    WHERE s.splited_data IN ('abc@mail', 'def@mail')
)
```

My answer is fairly similar to @Kitta answer in that we split the data out, and @Kitta is correct about the IN clause, but while their answer will work it will require you grouping your data back together to get a singular answer. Using the EXISTS clause will bypass all of that for you and only give you the data from the original table. That being said, please mark @Kitta as the answer if their answer works just as well for you.

Here is the test setup that I used

```
DROP TABLE Mails
GO
CREATE TABLE Mails
([To] VARCHAR(3000))

INSERT INTO dbo.Mails
(
    [To]
)
VALUES
('123@mail;abc@mail;aabc@mail')
,('nottheone@mail.com')
,('nottheone@mail.com;Overhere@mail.com')
,('aabc@mail;ewrkljwe@mail')
,('ewrkljwe@mail')

GO
DROP FUNCTION [split_string]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split_string]
(
@string_value NVARCHAR(MAX),
@delimiter_character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @result_set TABLE(splited_data NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE @start_position INT,
        @ending_position INT
SELECT @start_position = 1,
        @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter_character, @string_value)
WHILE @start_position < LEN(@string_value) + 1
        BEGIN
    IF @ending_position = 0 
       SET @ending_position = LEN(@string_value) + 1
    INSERT INTO @result_set (splited_data) 
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string_value, @start_position, @ending_position - @start_position))
    SET @start_position = @ending_position + 1
    SET @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter_character, @string_value, @start_position)
END
RETURN
END
GO


SELECT *
FROM dbo.Mails AS m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.split_string(m.[To], ';') s
    WHERE s.splited_data = 'abc@mail'
)
```

and it returns the correct row of '123@mail;abc@mail;aabc@mail'

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a multi-row subquery as an argument to the `dbo.split_string` function. Try to join your table function to the `Mails` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ms.*
    FROM Mails AS ms
    CROSS APPLY dbo.split_string(ms.[To], ';') AS s
    WHERE s.splited_data LIKE 'abc@mail'
```

If you can ubgrade your SQL Server up to 2016 (13.x), you can use built-in `STRING_SPLIT` table function instead of custom `dbo.split_string`.

Alternatively, you can achieve your goal with brute force and break down the comparison into simple terms such as follows:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Mails 
    WHERE 
        [To] LIKE 'abc@mail'
        OR [To] LIKE '%;abc@mail;%'
        OR [To] LIKE 'abc@mail;%' 
        OR [To] LIKE '%;abc@mail'
```

It might not be the best way, but it's pretty simple and doesn't require a split function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX() function.

```
select * from Mails where CHARINDEX('abc@mail.com', To) > 0
```

The CHARINDEX function checks for a substring within a given string and returns a value greater than zero if it is found. Here your string to search (substring) would be 'abc@mail.com' and the main string from where to search would be the "To" column.

More information about CHARINDEX() function can be found at below link
[https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/charindex.php#:~:text=SQL%20Server%3A%20CHARINDEX%20Function%201%20Description.%20In%20SQL,use%20the%20CHARINDEX%20function%20in%20SQL%20Server%20%28Transact-SQL%29](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/charindex.php#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%3A%20CHARINDEX%20Function%201%20Description.%20In%20SQL,use%20the%20CHARINDEX%20function%20in%20SQL%20Server%20%28Transact-SQL%29).

Comment: I don't think this answer might solve this issue. As it is mentioned in the question, if the substring we want to search is itself a substring of another substring,(eg: searching for abc@mail will be True if the [To] column contains aabc@mail ), So using this might not be the way to go.